# Referencing a specific repeater item instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, repeater, datamember

I've been looking all over StackOverflow and Google for an answer to this question, but I haven't been able to find anything.

I have a C# based ASP webpage that uses a repeater control to list information about students returned via a SQL procedure. To populate the repeater, the web app I am working in uses a `Student` class with `[DataMember]` properties representing each field in a SQL query result row. From my understanding, each item in the repeater control contains a separate instance of the `Student` class, with each instance representing a row in the query results. First, please let me know if the repeater operates differently than I understand.

If my understanding is correct, however, I would like to know if there is any way to reference a `student` instance contained in the specific item of the repeater control. I looked at a few methods associated with the repeater object, including:

```
repeater.Items        //This gets a collection of objects
repeater.DataMember   //Gets the 'specific table to bind'
repeater.DataSource   //References the SQL query results
```

None of these seem to reference the SQL row/'Student' instance.

Is there something that I am missing or not understanding correctly? I have been pouring over the MSDN site for the repeater control as well, but I may not be understanding all the terminology, if there is a solution on the page. The MSDN repeater page I am using is [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Please let me know if any additional information is needed. And thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items are stored in the repeater.Items statement and you can cast the items to whatever type you are expecting:

```
var student = (Student)repeater.Items[3];
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to do. Sometimes the answer is so simple. :P

I never realized you could use the index like that with the `.Items`.